# Crear consulta sql de relación en php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hola tego una tabla loterías con las columnas
id
nombre

Otra tabla sub_loterias con las columnas

id
nombre
imagen
id_loteria

Otra tabla resultados con las columnas

id
valor
fecha 
id_sub_loteria

Como seria la consulta sql que retorne ejemplo:

valor, fecha valor DESC de la tabla resultado y nombre, imagen de la tabla sub_loterias

Se trata una consulta que me arroje los últimos registros de cada sub_categoria por la fecha

Answer (score 0):

En el LIMIT pon el número según los que necesites.

```
SELECT res.valor, res.fecha, sub.nombre, sub.imagen 
FROM loterias lot
INNER JOIN sub_loterias sub ON lot.id = sub.id_loteria 
INNER JOIN resultados res ON res.id_sub_loteria = sub.id
ORDER BY res.fecha DESC
LIMIT 10
```